# Hadoop FS API File not found issue in MAPR

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hdfs

I am having issues while running the hadoop fs api to delete a directory. The programs throws exception even though i have a config in place. Need help in resolving the issue.

I am using the below maven dependencies

hadoop-common 2.4.1-mapr-1408
hadoop-core   2.4.1-mapr-1408
hadoop-client 2.7.1

Repo: http://repository.mapr.com/maven/

```
package com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ShellUtilities {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ShellUtilities.class);

    String target_dir = ReadProperties.getInstance().getProperty("target_dir");
    String tablename = "";

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = null;
    String dir = " ";

    public void DeleteDirectory(String tablename) {
        String fullpath = target_dir + tablename;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Deleting the HDFS directory " + fullpath);
            fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        Path directory = new Path(fullpath);

        try {
            if (fs.exists(directory)) {
                fs.delete(directory, true);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
16/02/19 23:04:33 ERROR cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils: File is not found: /opt/mapr/conf/mapr-clusters.conf
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\mapr\conf\mapr-clusters.conf (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.init(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:144)
    at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<init>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:72)
    at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<clinit>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.CoreDefaultProperties.<clinit>(CoreDefaultProperties.java:68)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProperties(Configuration.java:2062)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1081)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getDefaultUri(FileSystem.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.ShellUtilities.DeleteDirectory(ShellUtilities.java:24)
    at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.MainApp.importTables(MainApp.java:66)
    at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.MainApp.startTimeLogger(MainApp.java:51)
    at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:40)
16/02/19 23:04:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/02/19 23:04:35 ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2590)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.ShellUtilities.DeleteDirectory(ShellUtilities.java:24)
    at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.MainApp.importTables(MainApp.java:66)
    at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.MainApp.startTimeLogger(MainApp.java:51)
    at com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:40)
16/02/19 23:04:36 WARN fs.MapRFileSystem: Could not find any cluster, defaulting to localhost
Some error on socket 1472
2016-02-19 23:04:37,3423 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/client.cc:394 Thread: 4332 Failed to initialize client for cluster 127.0.0.1:7222, error Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown(108)
16/02/19 23:04:37 ERROR hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Could not create FileClient
16/02/19 23:04:37 INFO hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Deleting the HDFS directory /app/dev/SmartAnalytics/sqoop_temp/XXCCS_DS_CVDPRDLINE_DETAIL
Some error on socket 1488
2016-02-19 23:04:38,3434 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/client.cc:394 Thread: 4332 Failed to initialize client for cluster 127.0.0.1:7222, error Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown(108)
16/02/19 23:04:38 ERROR hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Could not create FileClient
16/02/19 23:04:38 INFO hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Deleting the HDFS directory /app/dev/SmartAnalytics/sqoop_temp/XXCCS_DS_INSTANCE_DETAIL
Some error on socket 1488
2016-02-19 23:04:39,3424 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/client.cc:394 Thread: 4332 Failed to initialize client for cluster 127.0.0.1:7222, error Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown(108)
16/02/19 23:04:39 ERROR hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Could not create FileClient
16/02/19 23:04:39 INFO hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Deleting the HDFS directory /app/dev/SmartAnalytics/sqoop_temp/XXCCS_DS_CVDPRDLINE_DETAIL
Some error on socket 1488
2016-02-19 23:04:40,3445 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/client.cc:394 Thread: 4332 Failed to initialize client for cluster 127.0.0.1:7222, error Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown(108)
16/02/19 23:04:40 ERROR hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Could not create FileClient
16/02/19 23:04:40 INFO hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Deleting the HDFS directory /app/dev/SmartAnalytics/sqoop_temp/XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE
Some error on socket 1488
2016-02-19 23:04:41,3525 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/client.cc:394 Thread: 4332 Failed to initialize client for cluster 127.0.0.1:7222, error Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown(108)
16/02/19 23:04:41 ERROR hiveconnector.ShellUtilities: Could not create FileClient
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with MapR from a remove machine you must install the "MapR Client", that contains all the dependencies for runtime.

This comes in addition to the maven dependencies that allows you to compile. The MapR Client is the set of Java library but also native library used to access MapR Cluster in the most efficient way.

I invite you to follow the steps documented here:

- [Setting up MapR Client](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Setting+Up+the+Client#SettingUptheClient-client)

This will allow you:

- to install you the client library
- configure the cluster "target" you want to use
- this will create the `/opt/mapr/..` folder